# Populating a map with JSON data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm populating a mapkit map with data from a `JSON` web service. Each row of data has a set of coords and is added to the map. Each row also has a URL. The problem with my code is that in the annotation callout accessory button for each map is using the same URL (always the last line of data from the array). The link is the very last link from the dictionary. In the `NSLOG` output below the 4th row is the link used for each callout. Each callout should have its own URL of course. The `dealAnnotation.title = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"vendor"];`
 is displaying the correct vendor name for each map object. It's just the URL that always displays the last URL from the dictionary.

Here's the log:

```
2013-02-27 11:17:35.077 link populated from map is http://www.http://www.****link1
2013-02-27 11:17:35.078 link populated from map is http://www.http://www.****link5
2013-02-27 11:17:35.079 link populated from map is http://www.http://www.****link3
2013-02-27 11:17:35.079 link populated from map is http://www.http://www.****link4
```

Here's my code:

The MKAnnotation with the right callout button method `pushToSafari`

```
    -(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    if ([annotation isMemberOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
   // annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;


    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(pushToSafari)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

   // annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);

    //add custom yd pin
    annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-pin-2.png"];

    return annView;
}
```

the code to populate the map with data. This is the line `link = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"link"];`
 that is setting the last url from the JSON for every callout button

```
#pragma mark - Populate Map
- (void)populateMap:(MKMapView*)map withDeals:(NSArray*) deals
{
    NSLog(@"DEALS" );
    for (NSDictionary *currentDeal in deals) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D  ctrpoint;
        ctrpoint.latitude = [[[currentDeal objectForKey:@"coords"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        ctrpoint.longitude =[[[currentDeal objectForKey:@"coords"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
        MKPointAnnotation  *dealAnnotation   = [[MKPointAnnotation  alloc] init];
        dealAnnotation.coordinate = ctrpoint;
        dealAnnotation.title = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"vendor"];
        link = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"link"];

        NSLog(@"link populated from map is %@",link);

        NSDictionary *currDict = @{
        @"EUR": @"€",
        @"GBP": @"₤",
        @"USD": @"$",
        @"BRL": @"R$"
        };

        NSString *currName = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"currency"];
        NSString *currency = [currDict objectForKey:currName];

            dealAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",currency,[[currentDeal objectForKey:@"price"] integerValue ]];

        NSLog(@"current deal currency sym is %@",[currentDeal objectForKey:@"id"]);


        [map setDelegate:self];
        [map addAnnotation:dealAnnotation];
    }
}
```

the viewDidAppear: method with the JSON code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"MAP VIEW APPEARED");

    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    // Configure the new event with information from the location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    NSLog(@"%f %f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude );
    if ( (double ) coordinate.latitude == 0 &&  (double )  coordinate.longitude == 0 ){
        CustomAlertView *alert = [[CustomAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No GPS Connection" message:@"GPS data is currently unavailable. Please ensure that Location Services are turned on in Settings." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }


    CLLocationDegrees currentLongitude=coordinate.longitude;
    CLLocationDegrees currentLatitude=coordinate.latitude;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:center];
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.****.com/coords=45.4640,9.1916&country=%@&maxdistance=3000&api.ofilter=track:iphone",APP_ID,lang];
    NSString *locationJsonString = [NSString
                                    stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query]                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                    error:nil];

    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:locationJsonString error:nil];
    NSString *currentCity = [[[results objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"key"];
    NSLog(@"Current city is : %@",currentCity);


    NSString *dealSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://****coords=45.4640,9.1916&maxdistance=20&api.ofilter=track:iphone",APP_ID,currentCity];

    NSString *dealsInCurrentLocationJsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dealSearch] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    //    SBJSON *parser2 = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dealResults = [parser objectWithString:dealsInCurrentLocationJsonString error: nil];

    NSArray *listOfDeals = [dealResults objectForKey:@"results"];

    [self populateMap:mapView withDeals:listOfDeals];

    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f", currentLongitude);
    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", currentLatitude);
}
```

and the method for the right callout button touch:

```
  -(IBAction)pushToSafari {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];

    NSLog(@"link touched from offers around me is %@",link);
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you call it JSON?  You're dealing with arrays and dictionaries.  The fact that the data originated as JSON is only barely relevant.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks! I made the changes

Comment: It's important to not bring in irrelevant details when looking at a problem.  It's good to know that the data's derived from JSON because that tells us that the dictionary/array tree will be "well formed", but once you've parsed the JSON there's nothing JSON-specific about the resulting data, and thinking of it as JSON can just confuse you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
link = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"link"];
```

Looks like it sets some instance variable named "link" to a url. So it is not specific to any annotation. There is only one variable named link, so whatever the last value it was set to is what will be there.

Also this line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

Does not retrieve "link" from any specific annotation or anything, just retrieves that "global" link variable. So it will be the same for any annotation.

**EDIT (Adding a way to make it work):**

So one way to do this is to extend MKPointAnnotation and add a link property to that. You can then add the right link using

```
dealAnnotation.link = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"link"];
```

Then make use of:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Which will get called when the accessory view is clicked if it is a UIButton or something that extends UIControl. Then you'll have access to the annotation view and can access it's annotation and get the link for that particular annotation. So delete the [rightButton addTarget:self...] line to get it to work.

Comment: any idea how I might get the link for the annotation that's been touched? Should I be trying         dealAnnotation.link = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"link"]; or something? thanks

Comment: I've added a way to make it work. Yes you'll need to set the link for each annotation, then make use of the built in delegate method to receive the click. Please accept the answer if you like it.

Comment: thanks again. I just have to figure out how to extend and add dealAnnotation.link. I added the NSString pointer "link" to the MapAnnotation.h file which is imported in the MapViewController but it doesn't recognize it yet.